# How to persist a binary search tree in mysql

Tags: mysql, binary-search-tree

What is the best way to store a binary search tree in Mysql ? Should each node be a table ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a table with a circular reference.

```
CREATE mytable(
id int not null auto_increment,
parent_id int,
PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

Comment: What would be the best way of selecting a subtree ?